# Image doesn't show when script is running on production server

Tags: php

I have this script that work with no problems on my XAMPP local host:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Gallery</title>
<style type="text/css">
body {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    width: 500px;
    color: #000000;
    position: relative;
}
.gallery {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.gallery li {
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 0;
    float: left;
    width: 120px;
    height: 100px;
}
.gallery img {
    background: #fff;
    border: solid 1px #ccc;
    padding: 4px;
    width: 110;
    height: 90;
}
.gallery a:hover img
{border: 1px solid #0000ff;
position: absolute;
top: 0; left: 0;
width:400;
height:300;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<ul class="gallery">
   <?php
//header("Content-type: image/jpg;\n");

  $db_connect = mysql_connect('localhost', 'Beta_tester', 'alfa1gama2');
        if(!$db_connect)
                {
                         die('Не може да се осъществи връзка с базата данни' . mysql_error());
                }
  mysql_select_db("Beta_tester", $db_connect);
  $rs = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM gallery WHERE oferta_id=2');


 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs))
  {
        echo '<li><a target="_blank" href="http://mysite/fimage.php?id='.$row['id'].'"><img src='.$row['location'].' alt="image"/></a></li>';
  }

?>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

On my local server it's ok, but when I upload it on the production server i get this output:

Pic1:
[image]

It's not shown very good but this is just an empty block with an icon of broken image.The head(content) is commented - I added it later because I saw a similar problem solved with this, but maybe I'm using it wrong or maybe it's something else.

Thanks

Leron

Comment: Look at the DOM, is the Image-URL correct?

Comment: Is `$row['location']` something like `C:\Documents and Settings\User\Desktop\image.jpg`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the location of the image (URL) is a valid one. Try to print the image url and try to open in another tab to make sure it's a valid URL.

Also, pass double-quotes on your image src attribute like:

```
<img src="'.$row['location'].'" alt="image" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is here:

```
<img src='.$row['location'].' alt="image"/>
```

Please show us the value of `$row['location']`

Answer (score 0):

Your browser must have a view source function. There you can see the whole output of the script. If something went wrong you should see it there.

Answer (score 0):

Check the value of the image src through firebug, and see the soruce. In this way you can figure out if your path is correct ornot.